# Java Mail IMAP taking lot of time to getting messages in mail box, 25s to get 20 messages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

There is a way to improve the performance for getting messages from the Javamail IMAP server?
i found some tips, but couldn't improve the performance. 
This method will get about 20 messages from a folder, and returning the formatted messages to a DTO, I tried to comment the lines to get attachments, and getting the recipients, but it doensnt change anything in the performance.

```
/**
 * Get all the emails that are inside the param folder
 *
 * @param folderId   folder to return the emails from the informed folder.
 * @param pageToken  pageToken to be used as pagination
 * @param maxResults maxResults to create a limit to the number of registers
 * @return {@link EmailsDTO} with all the messages
 */
public EmailsDTO getMessages(final String folderId, final String pageToken, final Integer maxResults) {
    final Properties properties = getServerInputProperties();
    final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    try {
        final EmailsDTO emailsDTO = new EmailsDTO();
        final List<EmailDTO> emailDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

        // connects to the message store
        final Store store = session.getStore(IMAP);
        store.connect(email, password);

        // opens the folder to search the messages
        final Folder folder = store.getFolder(folderId);
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        //set a pagination used to get the results in JavaMail
        final int pageStart = nonNull(pageToken) ? Integer.valueOf(pageToken) : 1;
        final int pageEnd = (pageStart + maxResults) > folder.getMessageCount() ? folder.getMessageCount() : pageStart + maxResults;


        // fetches new messages from server, starts with 1
        final Message[] messages = folder.getMessages(pageStart, pageEnd);

        final FetchProfile fetchProfile  = new FetchProfile();
        fetchProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        folder.fetch(messages, fetchProfile); // Load the profile of the messages in 1 fetch.

        for (final Message msg : messages) {
            final EmailDTO emailDTO = new EmailDTO();
            emailDTO.setId(msg.getHeader(MESSAGE_ID)[0]);
            emailDTO.setCc(this.parseAddresses(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)));
            emailDTO.setTo(this.parseAddresses(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)));
            emailDTO.setBcc(this.parseAddresses(msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)));

            emailDTO.setFrom(this.getFrom(msg.getFrom()));
            emailDTO.setRead(msg.getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN));
            emailDTO.setHasAttachments(this.hasAttachments(msg));
            emailDTO.setSubject(msg.getSubject());
            emailDTO.setMessage(this.getMessageContent(msg));

            emailDTO.setAttachments(this.getAttachements(msg));
            emailDTO.setDate(msg.getReceivedDate().toString());
            emailDTO.setParentFolder(msg.getFolder().getName());
            //TODO: see what need to put here emailDTO.setLabels();
            emailDTOList.add(emailDTO);
        }

        // disconnect
        folder.close(false);
        store.close();

        emailsDTO.setEstimatedNumberOfMessages(folder.getMessageCount());
        emailsDTO.setNextPageToken(String.valueOf(emailDTOList.size()));
        emailsDTO.setMessages(emailDTOList);
        return emailsDTO;
    } catch (final MessagingException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("couldn't get messages from the folder with id: %s", folderId), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Those calls to `store.getFolder()` and `folder.open()` can be awfully slow, often proportional to the number of messages in the folder. Try to keep the opened Folder object around so you can reuse it next time and amortise the cost of getting it.

Comment: I tried to keep it open, the performance changes just a little bit, about two seconds, but thank's for the comment :)

Comment: In that case you need to find out what takes the time, because one second per message is *wildly* out of the ordinary.

Comment: Look at the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and find a way to associate a time stamp with each line of output.  That will help you determine where the time is going.  Are you using IMAP or POP3?  Are you running in an app server?  Try changing `getDefaultInstance` to `getInstance`.  Post the debug output if it's still too slow.

Comment: I'm using an IMAP and running in an app server, I used the javamail debug to change some lines, but changing the getDefaultInstance  to getInstance improve a lot the performance, thank's for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  `for (final Message msg : messages)`, change `messages` to `folder.getMessages()`.

`messages` -> loads multiple times

`folder.getMessages()` -> loads in a single fetch, because you have used fetchProfile in this.